# ngRx state change getting lost

Tags: ngrx

Following some examples, I'm trying to manage the state of a sideBar component (open/closed).  I have defined some interfaces to manage my state objects:

```
export interface AppState {
  readonly layoutState: LayoutState;
}

export interface LayoutState {
  sideBarOpen: boolean;
}
```

I have a local variable in my Component that implements the LayoutState interface: `layout: LayoutState;`

I subscribe to my state in `ngOnInit`:

```
this.store.subscribe(appState => {
  this.layout = appState.layoutState;
  // (5)
});
```

I have a button in my UI that calls a function that contains this line: `this.toggleSideNav(this.layout.sideBarOpen);`

toggleSideNav looks like this:

```
toggleSideNav(currentState: boolean) {
    this.store.dispatch(new LayoutActions.ToggleSidebarAction(currentState)); // (1)
  }
```

Here is my effect:

```
@Effect()
  toggleSidebar$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(LayoutActions.TOGGLE_SIDEBAR)
    .switchMap((action: ToggleSidebarAction) =>
      this.layoutService.toggleSidebar(action.payload) // (2)
    )
    .map((layoutState: LayoutState) => {
       // (4)
      return new LayoutActions.ToggleSidebarSuccessAction(layoutState);
    });
```

Here is the `layoutService.toggleSidebar`  function:

```
toggleSidebar(currentState: boolean): Observable<LayoutState> {
    const rv = {
      sideBarOpen: !currentState
    };
    // (3) 
    return Observable.of(rv);
  }
```

---

Here is what I see when debugging.  At position:

(1) - `currentState` is `false` - as expected

(2) - `action.payload` is `false` - as expected

(3) - `rv` is `{sideBarOpen: true}` - as expected

(4) - `layoutState` is `{sideBarOpen: true}` - as expected

(5) - `this.layout` is `{sideBarOpen: false}` - !!

Why does the state get "lost" between (4) and (5)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was forgetting that after the Effect, it goes to the Reducer.  My Reducer only had this:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case Actions.LOAD_LAYOUT_SUCCESS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

I had to add a case for the `TOGGLE_SIDEBAR_SUCCESS` message to send the new state (contained in the payload):

```
switch (action.type) {
    case Actions.LOAD_LAYOUT_SUCCESS:
      return action.payload;
    case Actions.TOGGLE_SIDEBAR_SUCCESS:   <--
      return action.payload;               <--
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

Before adding that, the reducer was falling through to the default case, and returning `state`, which is the **old** state.